# Which MySQL users have access to a database?

Tags: mysql

How can I tell which MySQL users have access to a database and what privileges they have?

I seem to be able to get this information from phpMyAdmin when I click "Privileges". . .

```
                 Users having access to "mydatabase"
User     Host       Type               Privileges              Grant
myuser1  %          database-specific  ALL PRIVILEGES          Yes
root     localhost  global             ALL PRIVILEGES          Yes
myuser2  %          database-specific  SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE  No
```

. . . but I'd like to know how to perform this query from the command line.

(phpMyAdmin often shows me the SQL syntax of the command it is executing, but I don't see it in this case.)

Please note that I'm not asking what grants a particular user has (i.e. "SHOW GRANTS for myuser1") but rather, **given the name of a database, how do I determine which MySQL users have access to that database and what privileges they have?**  Basically, how can I get the chart above from the command line?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can append \G to the command to get results displayed in 'grid' veiw

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE Db = '<database name in LC>'\G;
```

Comment: +1 for \G not seen that before

Comment: When using `\G` you don't need a `;` anymore.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE Db = '<database name in LC>';
```

Comment: Thanks.  This answer does seem to output the same raw data as the chart in the question. . . but in a less readable format.  I guess presenting the data in the same format is an exercise for the reader. . . ;)

Answer (score 6):

You might give this a try, should provide the best readability:

```
select db 'DATABASE', host HOST, user USER from mysql.db where db = '<databasename>';
```

Something more memorizeable for the cli:

```
select db,host,user from mysql.db;
```